# Export error in ORACLE ERP (Financials) to Excel

Tags: oracle

Just want to ask for some inputs on the problem that we are encountering right now.
The export function suddenly is not working. When triggered, it just invoke the display screen but does not do anything.
This was working before. No changes were made on anything.

We checked the pop-up blockers and it is turned off.
Restarted the server and also checked tablespace and datafiles are all OK.
Checked the virtual memory during the exportation of data is also OK.
There is no error message on the screen or in the log files.

Any idea what may be the cause of the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in Oracle ebs R12? What version of Office? Explain your export (e.g.from Forms in tsv format)

Comment: Export? Are you talking about (re)publish and view? Log View? Output view (tools -> copy file)? R12? Need a lot more information here to attempt to help.

Comment: We are using 11i. WE access the export via File -> Export. This is being done while in the Invoice List screen. Once export is triggered, a pop-up screen specifying the Retrieval is ongoing after that nothing happens.

Comment: The office version is office 2000